# Which is the reflection factor of a satellite?

Tags: artificial-satellite, radiation

I'm trying to calculate the perturbations of a satellite due to the solar radiation pressure, but I'm not sure of which reflection factor to use. Do you know which are the common values of this factor?

Pd: I'm studying specifically the Scisat 1 satellite, but the reflection factor does not have to be the exact one, just an approximation.

Comment: I believe the answer will change drastically if the satellite relies on photovoltaic or not.

Answer (score 1):

Handwaving a bit, I expect this to be dominated by the [albedo of the solar panels](http://www.appropedia.org/The_effect_of_spectral_albedo_on_amorphous_silicon_and_crystalline_silicon_solar_photovoltaic_device_performance).

[image: Solar panel albedo peaks at 0.2-0.5 depending on the type of panel, the peak occurs at different wavelengths depending on the type of panel]

So albedo depends on the composition of the panel, and varies from 0.2-0.5. The contribution of the solar panels depends on their size relative to the rest of the satellite.

For SCISAT 1, this is easy:

[image: SICSAT is covered in solar panels]

Pretty much the entire sun-facing surface is solar panel. 
So all you need to know is the composition of the solar panels.

Comment: I don't remember the exact source, but I believe I read that 100% reflective surface provides twice the radiation propulsion as a 100% absorptive. I believe this pertains to conservation of momentum (photons stopped vs photons reversed 180 degrees)